# Force.com One App License and Content Management

Tags: force.com, editions, contentversion

I am trying to port an existing app to [Force.com One App License](http://www.salesforce.com/platform/platform-edition/). Here is the screen shot indicating the package dependency

[image: Package dependency]

I have two related questions here :

Q1 : Is feature "Content" available in Force.com app license ?

Q2 : For other Salesforce editions some have "Content Library" shown as feature, is it same as the "Content" feature indicated in screenshot above ?

Comment: Found this link about Force.com one app, seems it doesn't supports it : http://www.sfdcstatic.com/assets/pdf/datasheets/DS_Forcedotcom_EdCompare.pdf

Comment: There is a very similar license called chatter only that gives you a content license.  It's poorly named because it also gives you 10 custom objects plus read only to some of the standards.  See if it covers what you need.

Comment: Thanks @ShaneMcLaughlin ! this means Force.com one app license has "content" feature ?

Comment: Yes, it has content license included by default.  Make sure it covers everything else you need.  It has NO leads and only read only for accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very similar license called chatter only that gives you a content license. It's poorly named because it also gives you 10 custom objects plus read only to some of the standards. See if it covers what you need.

It's NOT the same as the force.com one app....it's a different license type.

Chatter Only    Also known as Chatter Plus. [Link](https://na1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/users_understanding_license_types.htm)